# fitVids() on bootstrap collapsed div - little bug opening multiple videos on single iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, fitvids

It's strange that such a well-known plugin comes with this issue. I fought for hours against it, and finally won. I think this post will be much appreciated by anyone who will fall into the same issue.

Suppose I have `Twitter-Bootstrap` (or another similar framework able to collapse/expand divs).  As we all know, an iframe can be targeted by a link, to display different URLs in it. In this case I'm referring to **different youtube videos shown into a unique iframe**.

```
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bfwg4wRcnDI" target="#youtube-frame">
             Open this video into the youtube iframe
    </a>
```

Suppose that `#youtubecontainer`, which is the parent of `#youtube-frame`, is collapsed.  I click on a link targeting `#youtube-frame` (like the code shown above), and through the jQuery `.onclick` event, `#youtubecontainer` gets expanded. Then `fitVids()` gets applied to it (it couldn't be done other than at this point on the code: indeed, before being expanded, the `#youtubecontainer` **didn't even exist for js**). But ... surprise!

**fitVids()** has taken the **'src' attribute** from the raw html and applied it to the iframe, **overriding the targeted link** I've just followed!!! 
It seems that the jQuery `fitVids()` plugin primairily refers to `#youtube-frame` 'src' attribute. My tries:

- If you leave a certain video in 'src', then that video will override any other video you'll click on.
- If you leave 'src' void, or you even remove completely the attribute, you won't solve the problem, and instead of an undesired video, you'll see just a black box. :D
- If you click for a second time on your link, you'll finally get it. But that's annoying.
- If you edit jquery.fitvids.js (var selectors), removing all the youtube 'iframe src' selectors and adding an entry for "#youtube_frame", that won't solve the issue too.

I was tired. I found out only a possible solution. I also hope that the creators of this script will enhance it... it's really **weird** that, when someone wants to keep the aspect ratio of a video element, instead of pointing to the element's ID this script messes things around with the 'src' attribute... Just like if a frame could only handle one src..... bah!

Possible solution:

1. Play with timings in jQuery and keep the right order, using `eventhandlers` or `setTimeout()`.  To do this, you need to change the way you link to your videos: instead of using `<a target="#youtube_frame"`, which fires earlier than the fitVids, you need to handle the click with jquery, changing the 'src' attribute of the iframe.

The right order is:

- 1) `Expand the Video Container`;
- 2) `fitVids()` on it;
- 3) `$('#youtube_frame').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))`

  (This last point sets the `src` attribute of the iframe, taking the video url from the link you've just clicked). Of course this must be put inside a function which gets executed on a click event.

If you have other solutions, please post them. I hope the creators of fixVids will get to know of this problem. I personally don't know how to completely fix the plugin, for it to leave alone the 'src' attribute.

```
 EDIT: I've just added a testcase: http://jsbin.com/huzedamu/2/edit?js,output 
 Unfortunately jsbin doesn't allow the loading of youtube videos through its website, 
 but you can copy/paste the following pastebin, you'll see the bug more clearly:

 [no matter what video you choose, at the first try you'll always get what's 
  inside the iframe 'src' attribute, which in the pastebin is a pretty old video]
```

**New Single-Paged TESTCASE > [**  http://pastebin.com/uLjJvhxC  **]**

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue tracker here: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open

Best to create a reduced test case.

Comment: Added. Please look at the main post. Didn't want to register to github just for this little thing.